# Fix for navFont can't be used on instance of type '...'?

Tags: swift, instance

I'm having some issues with `navFont`.
In my file `CustomAppearance.swift`, I'm getting an error

> navFont can't be used on instance of type 'Custom Appearance'.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

struct CustomAppearance {

   static let navFont = UIFont(name: "SF-UI-Text-Light", size: 17.0)

   func applyCustomAppearanceToNavigationBar() {
       UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
       UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
       UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: navFont!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor() ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I checked already. There are no questions similar to this. Except for one with a similar issue but totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use qualified name for static variables:

```
struct CustomAppearance {

    static let navFont = UIFont(name: "SF-UI-Text-Light", size: 17.0)

    func applyCustomAppearanceToNavigationBar() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: CustomAppearance.navFont!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()
        ]
    }
}
```

In future versions of Swift, syntax `Self.navFont!` will be also possible (see [Swift Evolution - Universal Self](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md))